# add JMH an existing spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, jmh, junit-jupiter

I have tried multiple tutorials to make a poc using jmh inside my test package but always faced: No matching benchmarks. Miss-spelled regexp.
My latest code:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
            <version>1.35</version>
        </dependency>
```

I downloaded 'JMH Java Microbenchmark Harness' plugin ( I tried also JMHack)

created these two classes

```
public class TestBenchmark
{

    @Benchmark
    public void init() {
        // Do nothing
    }

}
```

and

```
public class BenchmarkRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

And it's not working,

I will list couple of articles I already tried

[from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55878467/benchmarking-a-simple-spring-application-with-jmh)

[This tutorial](https://www.hascode.com/2017/10/microbenchmarks-with-jmh-java-microbenchmark-harness/)

[medium article](https://medium.com/lydtech-consulting/microbenchmarking-with-jmh-51e58a47eab2)

I think I must create a new project but It would be great if I could apply it to an existing project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I did simple integration of JMH with Spring Boot, you can find an example in https://github.com/stsypanov/spring-boot-benchmark

Comment: Thank you a lot, the missing part was wrong dependencies:
before I was adding jmh-core along with jmh-annprocess as dependencies 
Here we added jmh-core as a dependency and used jmh-annprocess as a plugin